# Python Django Framework - How to make up ownername and password in Models as login authentication?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-rest-framework, django-views

This is my class models. I wish to use the ownername and vehicle_password in class Vehicle for owner login.

```py
#this is my models.py. 
class AbstractOwnerInfo(models.Model): 
    ownername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vehicle_password = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
    abstract = True

#this is my class Vehicle. 
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    parkingnumber = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ownercontact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ownername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    vehicle_password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    IC = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehiclecompany = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pdate = models.DateField()
    intime = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='default_value')
    outtime = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parkingcharge = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
def __str__(self):
    return self.parkingnumber
```

And then I defined the classess, I wish to use the ownername and vehicle_password in class Vehicles as login credentials.

This is my defined member_login request and member_home request.

```py
def member_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ownername = request.POST.get('ownername')
        password = request.POST.get('vehicle_password')

        if ownername and password:
            user = authenticate(username=ownername, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "Logged in successfully.")
                return redirect('member_home')
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid login credentials. Please 
                try again.")

       return render(request, 'member_login.html')

      
def member_home(request):
    return render(request, 'member_home.html')
```

And this is my member_login.html page.

```html
{% csrf_token %}
<label for="ownername"><b>Ownername</b></label>
<input type="text" name="ownername" class="form-control" required>

<label for="vehicle_password"><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" name="vehicle_password" class="form-control" required>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary form-control">
</form>

{% if variable1 == ownername and logged_in %}
<script>
    alert('Logged in successfully');
    window.location = '{% url 'member_home' %}';
</script>
{% endif %}

{% if error == "yes" %}
<script>
    alert('Invalid Login Credentials, Try Again...');
</script>
{% endif %}
```

And then this is my member_home.html page.

```html
{% if owner.is_authenticated %}
<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome <b style="text-transform: capitalize; color: 
blue">{{ ownername }}</b>
{% endif %}
```

I couldn't login and the webpage refreshes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you help me check my work

Comment: You are doing it wrong the authenticate method uses `User` model for authentication but you doing it with your custom model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override [AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL)
in order to define your custom model for authetication as by default django own `User` model is used for authentication.

It is recommended to do this in the start of your project as it will mess up your migrations that have already been applied here is a note from documentation:

> It is intended to be set at the project start, and the model it
> refers to must be available in the first migration of the app that it
> lives in

The documentation also describes how to do it [mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

You can also use [AbstractBaseUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser) like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin


class AbstractOwnerInfo(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ownername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "ownername"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ownername
```

I didn't think there is any way of renaming password field I maybe wrong but didn't find it anywhere.